# How to work with previous row's value using ootb functions?

Tags: sql

I have a table **States** that has data ordered by column **ID1** and per each month as shown in below snippet. Values of column STATE can have different values per each month `unknown , Active , InActive` and **DependentSTATE** column would be empty initially

**Expected transformed States table**

I am trying to update the DependentState column that is derived from **STATE** column i.e Whether or not the State for the month is different than that for the  month prior , if different from previous update dependent state with `1` , if same then with `0`

I was trying to do this with window based functions in snowflake but unable to conclude on how to acheive the transformed table. Any help is much appreciated.

Eg:

- For ID1 for month of May the state is `unknown` and dependantstate column value is `1`
- For ID1 for month of June the state is `active` and dependantstate column value is `1`
- For ID1 for month of July the state is `Inactive` and dependantstate column value is `1`
- For ID1 for month of August the state is `Inctive` and dependantstate column value is `0`
- For ID2 for month of May the state is `Active` and dependantstate column value is `1`
- For ID2 for month of June the state is `InActive` and dependantstate column value is `1`
- For ID2 for month of July the state is `InActive` and dependantstate column value is `0`
- For ID2 for month of August the state is `Active` and dependantstate column value is `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon's answer is generally correct, but misses one part: The question not only wants to look for the previous month, but the previous month for each id. For that, you'll need to add the keyword `PARTITION BY` to the `OVER` clause:

```sql
select t.*,
       (case when state = lag(state) over (partition by id order by month)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as state
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when state = lag(state) over (order by month)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as state
from t;
```